# how to get data from NSMutableArray (JSON)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Json :

```
{
   "Latitude" : "-6.260834",
   "SubPortfolio" : "ASL",
   "Idmall" : "1",
   "Logo" : "http://example.com/abc/new.png",
   "Menus" : "store, hotel",
   "Longitude" : "106.811847",
   "Name" : "New Hotel Area",
   "Pics" : "http://example.com/abc/htl.jpg"
}
```

Code :

```
var json: JSON = JSON.nullJSON
var adsImages : [UIImage] = []
var idMalls = NSMutableArray()
var Latitudes = NSMutableArray()
var Logos = NSMutableArray()
var Longitudes = NSMutableArray()
var Menus = NSMutableArray()
var Names = NSMutableArray()
var Pics = NSMutableArray()
var SubPortfolioCds = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.setupData()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
}

func setupData() {
        RestAPIManageCollection.sharedInstance.getAllMall{ json -> Void in
            for (index: String, subJson:JSON) in json {
                let idMall: AnyObject = json["idMall"].object
                self.idMalls.addObject(idMall)

                let Latitude: AnyObject = json["Latitude"].object
                self.Latitudes.addObject(Latitude)

                let Logo: AnyObject = json["Logo"].object
                self.Logos.addObject(Logo)

                let Longitude: AnyObject = json["Longitude"].object
                self.Longitudes.addObject(Longitude)

                let Menus: AnyObject = json["Menus"].object
                self.Menus.addObject(Menus)

                let Name: AnyObject = json["Name"].object
                self.Names.addObject(Name)

                let Pic: AnyObject = json["Pics"].object
                self.Pics.addObject(Pic)

                let SubPortfoliocd: AnyObject = json["SubPortfoliocd"].object
                self.SubPortfolioCds.addObject(SubPortfoliocd)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.tableView.reloadData() })

               println(idMall[0])  //1st println
               println(json["idMall"].stringValue)  //2nd println
               println(self.idMall)  //3rd println

            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get data from json, I try to println but return data nil...

 1st print 

 2nd print

 3rd print

 
 
I try with different print but it's same result...or I've something wrong on my code...?
 
but if I try println(json) I can get all json data...
how can i get json data for just 1 field specific?

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use Object mapper instead of manual parsing. 
One of my favorite is MJExtension. One of the fastest and efficient way to do conversion between JSON and model.

https://github.com/CoderMJLee/MJExtension

There are lot other:

- https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle
- https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper